# Outlook 2003 *.pst

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2003, password-recovery, pst

Forgot password for Outlook data file 2003. Is there a way to restore it or do something to reset or delete. I just don't know what to do now. Did a system kickback, but it didn't help. No this recovery point when the password has not been set. May try to look in the vault? But I don't know where Outlook 2003 stores all passwords and accounts. Really need your help!

Comment: related [Recovering Outlook .pst password?](http://superuser.com/q/119803/172747)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [this](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/pst_password.html) software, (I did not try this, I just found it on the web)
**but** as Dave mentioned, you can never trust a program like this!
If it is really important for you, than safest solution is if You make a [virtual machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_machine), copy the `.pst` file in it, than install the program (or any similar programs) **on** the virtual PC, crack the `.pst`, copy the cracked `.pst` back to your PC, and destroy the virtual machine.

This is unofficial but might work.